# Can the dependent of UK Tier 2 ICT visa work in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

Can the dependent of UK Tier 2 ICT visa work in UK?
The BRP of the dependent mentions "Restricted work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they can, although there are some restrictions as detailed on the UK Government page [PBS Dependant - Partner](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-partner) (under "What you need to know"), linked from [Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/family-members):

> Blockquote
>
> With PBS Dependant - Partner you can:
>
> work in the UK (if you are the dependant of a Tier 4 student you may not be allowed to work, see the guidance for the specific requirements for working in the UK during your leave)
>
> You cannot:
>
> work as a trainee Doctor or Dentist unless specified evidence is provided
> receive public funds, like unemployment or housing benefit
> work as a sportsperson or sports coach